# Flutter - How do I change a value straight after I setState

Tags: flutter, state, rendering, setstate

I have a `bool fetchNew`. It's initialized as false and I have a function refresh() that sets it to true. How do I set it to false right after setState preventing the rerender?

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  bool fetchNew = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  refresh() {
    setState(() {
      fetchNew = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

I thought initState() would set it to false again after rerender but the way I understand initState is that it will only fire once to inject the Widget into the widget tree.

Comment: You want to set it true for 1 second only and change it to false again?

Comment: Yes basically. setState rerenders the widget. I just want it to be false right after setting it true so it won't rerender twice. I couldn't find any flutter lifecycle that would achieve that. Something like change state after rerender without rerending again.

Comment: Just add `fetchNew = false` after the `setState()` in your `refresh()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try this?

```
setState(() {
  fetchNew = true;
  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100, () {
     fetchNew = false;
  });
});
```